# Why npm run dev command is showing error cannot find module '. /dist/rx'

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, npm

```
C:\Users\sharm\codeweb\eth-to-do-list>npm run dev
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.

> eth-to-do-list@1.0.0 dev
> lite-server

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module './dist/rx'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\sharm\codeweb\eth-to-do-list\node_modules\rx\index.js
- C:\Users\sharm\codeweb\eth-to-do-list\node_modules\browser-sync\dist\file-watcher.js
- C:\Users\sharm\codeweb\eth-to-do-list\node_modules\browser-sync\dist\browser-sync.js
- C:\Users\sharm\codeweb\eth-to-do-list\node_modules\browser-sync\dist\index.js
- C:\Users\sharm\codeweb\eth-to-do-list\node_modules\lite-server\lib\lite-server.js
- C:\Users\sharm\codeweb\eth-to-do-list\node_modules\lite-server\bin\lite-server
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\sharm\codeweb\eth-to-do-list\node_modules\rx\index.js:1:10)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\sharm\\codeweb\\eth-to-do-list\\node_modules\\rx\\index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\sharm\\codeweb\\eth-to-do-list\\node_modules\\browser-sync\\dist\\file-watcher.js',
    'C:\\Users\\sharm\\codeweb\\eth-to-do-list\\node_modules\\browser-sync\\dist\\browser-sync.js',
    'C:\\Users\\sharm\\codeweb\\eth-to-do-list\\node_modules\\browser-sync\\dist\\index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\sharm\\codeweb\\eth-to-do-list\\node_modules\\lite-server\\lib\\lite-server.js',
    'C:\\Users\\sharm\\codeweb\\eth-to-do-list\\node_modules\\lite-server\\bin\\lite-server'
  ]
}
```

Comment: We get the same error on our build server when we run it for the first time, but when we run it a second time the error goes away. Did you find a solution?

Comment: In our case the contents of the node_modules folder were corrupt. We had to explicitly delete the node_modules folder and run `npm install` again.